# How to iterate through a collection of maps of different kinds using range based 'for' loops?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++17

I can iterate through a map as follows:

```
std::map<int, std::string> intMap = { {1, "one"}, {2, "two"}, {3, "three"} };

for (const auto &[k, v]: intMap)
{
    doSomething(k, v);
}
```

I have another map (of different type and size) defined as follows:

```
std::map<float, std::string> floatMap = { {1.0, "one"}, {2.0, "two"}};
```

I want to do the same thing for this map as well (`doSomething(k, v)` is templated)

```
for (const auto &[k, v]: floatMap)
{
    doSomething(k, v);
}
```

Is there a way where I can do this for both the maps by iterating through the collection of maps?

Something like:

```
for (const auto &map: {intMap, floatMap})
{
    for (const auto &[k, v]: map)
    {
        doSomething(k, v);
    }
}
```

This however gives the error:

> cannot deduce type of range in range-based 'for' loop

What's the cleanest way (> C++17) to iterate through a collection of maps (of different kinds) using range-based 'for' loops?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use fold expression to expand immediately invoked lambda to do this:

```
[](const auto&... maps) {
  ([&] {
    for (const auto& [k, v] : maps)
      doSomething(k, v);
   }(), ...);
}(intMap, floatMap);
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/c8j5ev9rP)

Comment: That works. Thanks! Can you please explain the syntax around the internal lambda function - `(), ...)` ? Why is it inside a paranthesis and why do we pass `...`, eventhough we capture the `maps` argument using `&` ?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand it now using this reference: https://www.foonathan.net/2020/05/fold-tricks/

Comment: Writing `foreach_arg(...)(lambda)` puts the arcane pack manipulation in one place, away from the business logic.